# About the Deep Copy of Provider

Tags: flutter, provider

I don't know if deep copy is supported in Providers. For example, if I get a value in Provider, I want to assign that value to a new variable, and that variable doesn't change because Provider changes.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a good idea to give more context, codes or example to let us answer your question correctly.

But, for your question, yes you can, depending on your use case. If you use Provider.of(context), you can set the listen value to false for which value you don't want to change.

`var fixedValue = Provider.of(context, listen: false)`, will not change in value

`var value = Provider.of(context)`, will change